# Autocomplete для vim

Tags: vim

Подскажите плагин, который будет делать автокомплит по проекту, а не просто по языку. К примеру, я создал класс, и когда я буду его использовать, то vim будет подсказывать методы и свойства это класса.

Comment: какой язык программирования и ось?

Comment: Языки javascript, php, ruby. Платформа mac/linux

Comment: для javascript не получиться - там классов нет (там объекты. а что там храниться - это часто только в рантайме можно узнать).
Руби - https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport
а вот с php - даже не знаю.

Answer (score 3):

Упомянутый выше 
https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe
достаточно монструозный и автодополняет всё ко всему.
Для начала попробуйте просто в .vimrc прописать

```
au FileType php setl ofu=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

или какой вам язык нужен и вызывать по

> crtl n

Лучше подходить со стороны языка и искать комплит для него. 
Так же не плохой плагин для JS https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim
**node** и **npm** должны быть установленны в системе

В любом случае если вы определите объекты через фасад или свойства будут содержать объекты переопределённые по родителю или трэйту, то никакая автокомплитка вам не поможет.

Answer (score 2):

[YouCompleteMe](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/)

Поддержка многих языков, + того что ты хочешь

Comment: @Other на вопрос "посоветуйте плагин" сложно ответить иначе, чем ссылкой. Код плагина прямо в ответе разместить?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, описание плагина можно перевести и гифку вставить, например.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в любом случае - это ответ-ссылка. А это, вроде, не поощряется.